# socket.io client not receiving

Tags: node.js, websocket, express, socket.io

I am using socket.io in nodejs and I am able to send data from client to server. But when I emit from server, the client does not seem to be receiving this...
What am i missing ?

### server:

```
socket = io.listen(app);
socket.sockets.on('connection', function(client){ 
client.on('something-from-client', function(msg){
           console.log(msg);
       //do something.
       client.emit('some-result',{"total":docs.length});
   });
});
```

### client:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9999');
socket.on('some-result', function(data){
    console.log('received from server', data);
});
socket.emit("something-from-client",  {"lat":lat, "lng":lng});
```

Comment: 2 Things
1/ Can you please try on server - `client.send("Blah Blah");`
On client - 
socket.on('message', function(m){
  alert(m);
});

2/ On client change to => `var socket = io.connect();` , host and port are not required, it is autodetected.

If you want to see a working example example => https://github.com/parj/node-websocket-demo

Answer (score 1):

Ok got it working, if express is being used, some minor changes need to be done on server side

```
var port = 8111;
var server = express.createServer();
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(port);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

As promised - Working code - https://github.com/parj/node-websocket-demo/tree/socket_emit

CF Reference - http://socket.io/#how-to-use