# Socket.io Error (socket.send is not a function)

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying out Websockets/Node.js/Socket.io/Express for the first time and I'm trying to create a simple chat program. Everything runs fine and I see both clients in my node termial.

But when I try to execute my `socket.send()`, I get an error in Firefox (socket.send is not a function). It doesn't complain about `socket.connect()` so I know the socket.io.js is loaded.

Here is my server code:

```
var sys = require('util');
var express = require('express');
var io = require('socket.io');

var app = express.createServer();
app.listen(8080);
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.html', {
        title: 'Chat'
    });
});

var socket = io.listen(app);

socket.on('connection', function (client) {
    client.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log("Message: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        socket.broadcast(message);
    });
    client.on('disconnect', function () {});
});
```

My client code:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

var socket = new io.Socket("http://localhost:8080");
socket.connect();
```

Then I do some code to get the chat message and send it.

```
socket.send(JSON.stringify(values));
```

Comment: What version of Socket.IO do you have?

Comment: @alessioalex io.version = '0.8.7'; I tried emit() which doesn't give an error but it doesn't send anything :S

Comment: This has been covered in other stackoverflow q/a cf => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386984/socket-io-client-not-receiving/8603282#8603282, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627626/socket-io-not-sending-a-message-to-all-connected-sockets/8593305#8593305, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510260/node-js-server-is-not-working-properly/8593810#8593810, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069202/info-unhandled-socket-io-url/8593409#8593409, example using send - https://github.com/parj/node-websocket-demo, example using emit - https://github.com/parj/node-websocket-demo/tree/socket_emit

Answer (score 2):

### **Explanations**

You haven't initialized Socket.io correctly on the server-side and client-side.

- **Client Side**

  1. `new io.Socket("http://localhost:8080");` doesn't give you the object that you want, you need `new io.connect("http://localhost:8080");`.
  2. You need to wait until the client is connected to the server before sending a message.
- **Server side**

  1. `socket` is the object send back by Socket.IO, you need to use `socket.sockets` to have access to `on`.
  2. To broadcast a message, you need to use the client object like this: `client.broadcast.send()`
  3. The variable `data` doesn't exist on your broadcast. You probably mean `message`.

### **Solution**

- **Server**

  ```
  var sys = require('util'),
      express = require('express'),
      io = require('socket.io'),
      app = express.createServer();

  app.listen(8080);

  app.use(express.static(__dirname));

  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.render('index.html', {
          title: 'Chat'
      });
  });

  var io = io.listen(app);

  io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
      client.on('message', function (message) {
          console.log("Message: " + JSON.stringify(message));
          client.broadcast.send(message);
      });

      client.on('disconnect', function () {});
  });
  ```
- **Client**

  ```
  <script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
      var socket = new io.connect("http://localhost:8080"),
          connected = false;

      socket.on('connect', function () {
          connected = true;
      });

      // Use this in your chat function.
      if (connected) {
          socket.send(JSON.stringify(values));
      }
  </script>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`socket.broadcast(message);` should be `io.sockets.emit('key', message);`

when you use the socket object passed in threw the connect event your only emitting information to that client, to emit to all clients you have to use `io.sockets.emit()`.

also with `socket.send(JSON.stringify(values));` I think you want to do `socket.emit(namespace, data);`

see my connection file from one of my projects here: https://github.com/AdminSpot/HangoutCanopy/blob/master/javascripts/connection.js

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for socket.io to connect on the client side

```
var socket = new io.Socket("http://localhost:8080");
socket.connect();
socket.on('connect', function() {
  socket.emit('event', data);
});
```